# Delphi Xe10 Datasnap : Image function sending not working

Tags: rest, delphi, jpeg, datasnap, delphi-10-seattle

I have a problem with the send function. My program worked correcly in Xe8 but with the upgrade to Xe10, I have a problem : encryption ?

I have create a simple project datasnap with juste the bugging function like that

```
procedure TServerMethods1.test3;
VAR
  a : string;
begin
  a := LoadFileToStr('C:\demo\Bitmaps\Mazak_Matrix.JPG');



  GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseContentType :=  'image/jpeg';
  GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseCode := 200;
  GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContent := a;
  GetInvocationMetaData.CloseSession := True;


end;
```

And the function LoadFileToStr

```
function LoadFileToStr(const FileName: string): AnsiString;
var
  FileStream : TFileStream;
begin
  FileStream:= TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
   if FileStream.Size>0 then
   begin
    SetLength(Result, FileStream.Size);
    FileStream.Read(Pointer(Result)^, FileStream.Size);
   end;
  finally
   FileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Actually, the data was correct until

```
GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContent := a;
```

The responseContent destroy the data, like you can see on the hex editor. An example. The entire file is not corrupt, just a few characters.

Original Picture

[image: original picture] 
[image]

After sending by the server

[image]
[image: Image sending by Rest server]

Someone has encountered the same bug? If going directly a stream that works, but it doesn't interest me.

Thanks !

Comment: Binary data is not a string, treat it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Try something like this.

```
procedure TAPI.GetFile(UID: string);
var
  LFS: TFileStream;
  I: Integer;
  LByte: Byte;
begin
  try
    LFS := TFileStream.Create('e:\image.jpg', fmOpenRead);
    for I := 0 to Pred(LFS.Size) do
    begin
      LFS.Read(LByte, 1);
      GetInvocationmetaData.ResponseContent := GetInvocationmetaData.ResponseContent + Char(LByte);
    end;
    GetInvocationmetaData.ResponseContentType := 'image/jpeg';    
  finally
    LFS.Free;
  end;  
end;
```